# Can't install Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Please help me, i try setup "Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile" from both Visual studio 2015 ISO and web installer but it's not successful.

This is download link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=619310

Log file here:

http://hastebin.com/pafequlece.tex

Answer (score 5):

There are some requirements for using the emulator. You need

- Hyper-V
- SLAT (Second Level Address Translation)
- Data Execution Prevention (DEP)
- min. 4GB memory
- 64bit
- min. Pro-Edition (Win 10 Home does not support Hyper-V)

So you can develop Universal Apps on **Home**, but you can only test it with Mobile Emulator on **Pro**. Or did I understand anything wrong?
If not, I should build my app for Android ;-)

**Update**: I found [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html) article about how to initialize Hyper-V (on Pro).
[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3190.hyper-v-how-to-fix-bios-errors-enabling-hyper-v.aspx) is an article about the BIOS settings for Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the Windows version you are using.

Windows Emulator requires a Windows Pro Edition. It needs to work virtually and hence need Hyper-V, After installing Windows 10 Pro edition, go to your BIOS and check for the Hyper-V.

Also, to check whether your OS supports Hyper-V, check this in the BIOS settings.

If you are using Windows Home Edition then go to Windows Store to upgrade it to Pro version.

Alternatively you can install third party emulators.

Or, you can use physical Windows phone device.

Remember, Windows 10 is recommended for Windows devices programming.