# Windows 10 Mobile emulator fatal error during installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am attempting to install the Windows 10 mobile emulators for visual studio, but the installer crashes every time. I have not been able to determine the cause. The installed just informs me of a fatal error during installation and then halts. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get the installer to work?

My log file is here:
[Windows 10 Mobile Install Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jcHqQY5Rn-T2xiSkdKRWQxbFk/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the requirements for using the emulator ok? Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109008/cant-install-microsoft-emulator-for-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log I see the error code `-2146498548` while trying to activate Hyper-V:

> Dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
>   /NoRestart exited with code = -2146498548 
> Hyper-V feature status:
>   Failed to Enable

which means

> CBS_E_UNKNOWN_UPDATE - named update not present in package

Looks like you use the Windows 10 Home Edition, which doesn't include Hyper-V.

Comment: Thanks for finding that! I have a windows 10 pro license, but I recently got a new laptop and it had home instead of pro. I'll just need to upgrade from home to pro in order to use hyper-v. Thanks for the help!